# WP7 -Dealing with Async JAVA based SOAP Service Exception Handling

Tags: windows-phone-7, asynchronous, exception

I've a JAVA based SOAP Web service which i am consuming in WP7 (Silverlight Client).I'm able to invoke it and retrieve the response back , but could not find any way to handle the server side SOAP exceptions arising out of scenarios like Web service offline , server down etc.

I've put in Try Catch block too but it seems they are never reaching ...exception goes out to References.cs file (proxy class file auto generated when Service is add referenced).After this application just crashes.I know all UI level exceptions are ultimately caught at application level if unhandled at UI level .But in this case I'm unable to find a way out to resolve this problem .

Any help would be of great help ...Here is the simple code ...

```
try
{
DownloadPartsService.DownloadNewClient downloadData = new DownloadNewClient();
            downloadData.downLoadDataCompleted += new EventHandler<downLoadDataCompletedEventArgs>(AsyncCallback);
            downloadData.downLoadDataAsync("FULL");
}
catch (exception)
{
    throw myException  // this block is never reached even if exception occurs..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is generally advisable to not use WebClient but WebRequest because WebClient party runs on the UIThread. You should be able to catch any exception at the EndGetResponse level.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention ..I'm using JSON with SOAP as an exchange pattern .. Could you pls. elaborate more on what you mean to say..

Comment: the `DownloadNewClient` will be a auto-generated service client not a `WebClient`.  Also I'm not sure that it is true that WebClient should not be used generally.  For many operations IMO it is preferable.  Only when you have significant non-UI processing to do after a response is received __OR__ if you have a more complex scenario that WebClient doesn't support would you drop down to the WebRequest level.